# Python Use data/time as x-axis?

Tags: python, date, time, matplotlib, plot

I'm playing around with my raspberry pi sensors and trying to make a decent plot of the readings. 
Now I am savind all the data into a google docs: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqwhQwJogqG0dDBiU1RuNzlKM1V5OXB3dkRPamctbnc#gid=0 
And using both data+time and a unix timestamp to save the time.

Plotting with the unix time works perfectly

[image: graph]

But I would like to use real time as the axis (or as a subaxis) But I can't seem to read it in nor plot it.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#import data
data = np.loadtxt('DHT11.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1,
                     usecols = (0,2,3,4,5,6), unpack = 1)

#id, unixtime, temp, humidity, lightlevel, lightvolt

i = data[0]
time = data[1]
temp = data[2]
hum = data[3]
light_lv =  1/data[4]*1000
light_v = data[5]


if 1:

    host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()

    offset = 60
    new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                        axes=par2,
                                        offset=(offset, 0))

    par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)



    #host.set_xlim(0, 2)
    #host.set_ylim(0, 2)

    host.set_xlabel("Time (unix)")
    host.set_ylabel("Temperature (C)")
    par1.set_ylabel("Humidity (%)")
    par2.set_ylabel("Light (A.U.)")

    p1, = host.plot(time, temp)
    p2, = par1.plot(time, hum)
    p3, = par2.plot(time, light_lv)

    #par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
    #par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

    host.legend()

    host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
    par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
    par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

    plt.draw()
    plt.show()

    #plt.savefig("Test")
```

Could anyone please help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom formatter (see below), but if you do it that way you'd need to define the formatter for each axis, `host`, `par1`, `par2`.

I think an easier solution would be to convert your `time` to Python `datetime.datetime` objects, and let Matplotlib handle the formatting. You could still use a custom formatter if you don't like how Matplotlib formats the dates.

```
import datetime as DT
time = [DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(t/1000) for t in time]
...
p1, = host.plot(time, temp)
p2, = par1.plot(time, hum)
p3, = par2.plot(time, light_lv)
```

---

By the way, you can define `i`, `time`, `temp`, etc. directly (without using the temp variable `data`):

```
i, time, temp, hum, light_lv, light_v = np.loadtxt(
    'DHT11.csv', delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1,
    usecols = (0,2,3,4,5,6), unpack = 1)

time = [DT.datetime.fromtimestamp(t/1000) for t in time]
light_lv = 1.0/light_lv*1000
```

---

If the `x-axis` values are Python `datetime.datetime` objects, to set a custom formatter, use

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

If the `x-axis` values are timestamps, use

```
import datetime as DT
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
xfmt = ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda timestamp, pos: DT.fromtimestamp(x/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

Where `ax` is `host`, `par1`, and/or `par2`.

Comment: I'm getting errors when doing that.
http://pastebin.com/iHGGAKRb

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'`

Comment: My mistake. `DT.fromtimestamp` should have been `DT.datetime.fromtimestamp`.

Comment: That works! Though they are completely overlapping now. Where should the `plt.xticks(rotation=25)`go to not get ignored?

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your data to `pandas` time series, it will automatically do that for you. it will also choose appropriate label format according to frequency of the data. For example if your data come in seconds:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 100
idx = pd.date_range( start=dt.datetime.now( ), periods=n, freq='S' )
ts1= pd.Series( np.sin( np.linspace( 0, 4 * np.pi, n ) ), index=idx)
ts2= pd.Series( np.cos( np.linspace( 0, 4 * np.pi, n ) ), index=idx)

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8, 6) )
ax = fig.add_axes( [.05, .05, .9, .9] )

ts1.plot( ax )
ts2.plot( ax )
(ts1 - ts2).plot( ax )
```

you get this:

[image: ts3]

and if you have daily data:

```
ts= pd.Series( np.sin( np.linspace( 0, 4 * np.pi, n ) ),
               index=pd.date_range( start=dt.datetime.now( ), periods=n, freq='D' ))
ts.plot( )
```

[image: ts2]

Comment: I don't think that this will work with my overplots, as I am plotting 3 (latermore) graphs in one thing.

Comment: @Coolcrab it does, simply use `ts.plot( ax )` where `ax` is the axis you have created, and it will plot it over that given axis